# How to share image on facebook wall using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a share button in my asp.net application,i want to share image on user facebook wall when user click on share button.The image which i want to share is in image folder inside asp.net application.

Comment: What have you done? Have you gone through their docs?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by the following link. You can follow it. I think it should work

http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/12/posting-to-facebook-wall-in-asp-netc-using-graph-apipart-5/

Comment: hi Atish thanks for link.Can you please tell me where to write the code from above link,on page load or click event of button.I am writing on click event of share button but image is not being shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code for sharing on twitter and facebook for the specific post using C#. On Code behind you can call Javascript function and provide specific post URL and sharer website e.g facebook or twitter.

```
<a onclick=\"socialWindow("#PostURL"','fb');\"><a onclick=\"socialWindow("#PostURL','twitter');\">


function socialWindow(posturl, medium) {

var address = 'http://yougagged.com/gag/PostURL';
var sharer;
switch (medium) {
    case 'fb':
        {
            sharer = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + address;
            break;
        }
    case 'twitter':
        {

            sharer = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=' + address + '&url=' + address;
            break;
        }
}
var w = 640;
var h = 460;
var sTop = window.screen.height / 2 - (h / 2);
var sLeft = window.screen.width / 2 - (w / 2);
var sharer = window.open(sharer, "sharer", "status=1,height=" + h + ",width=" + w + ",top=" + sTop + ",left=" + sLeft + ",resizable=0"); }
```